# Limit of dropdown list in Power Apps

Tags: office365, powerapps

how are you ?

I need you people !
I made an application with Power Apps but i have a problems I hava an Excel with 2k + items and the dropdow list have limit in 500 Items do you have an idea to skip this limit.

I need you ! DX

Thank you, and have a nice day !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TFQj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to increase the row limit by going to

Power Apps -> File -> Settings -> Advanced Settings

and then increasing the Data Row Limit for non-delegable queries

[image: Power Apps row limit setting]

Answer (score 0):

No user needs 500 choices (nor even 50!) in a Dropdown. Talk to your users, create a Collection of all 2k, sure, but then filter the Collection down to a prioritized, small number of items for the Dropdown.

It appears that a Dropdown can *see* records beyond 500, but not display records beyond 500.

**To test:**

1. Add a Button control to your app
2. Set its `OnSelect` property to

```
ForAll(
    Sequence(2001),
    Collect(colProof, Value)
)
```

3. Wait for a few minutes...
4. Add a Dropdown control to your app
5. Set its `Items` property to `Sort(colProof, Value, Descending)`

After a short while, you'll see items 2001-1502 show in the Dropdown along with an error message.

So answer is "No, you cannot display more than 500 choices in a PowerApps Dropdown"

[image]

Comment: You are right thank you! But can we go beyond 2k choices ?